# How to update value inside object of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, mongodb

I have this document in mongodb.
[image]
I want to update the PENDING status to ORDER PLACED. How do I do that?
I am try with this but not working. First I am finding the document by ordered then update it.

```
for (let item in orderedProducts) {
await db.collection("orders").updateOne(
          { order_id: parseInt(myrequest.orderId) },
          {
            $set: {
              `ordered_products.${item}.orderStatus`: "Order Placed"
            }
          })}
```

Comment: From the screenshot, your `order_id` is a float, but you are try to cast the value via `parseInt()`, it will result the value in integer. Are you sure is this correct? While what is the `item` value? Aside, it is **very rare** that use a float value as id.

Comment: I am using just for development and it is working fine. Item is the key of object like KEY-CAS-001-GRN. Just tell me how to update order_status

Comment: [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OxNrDcIMVta). By right this would be worked, if the document is found and the parsed key is existed in the `ordered_products` property. Think you need to capture the result from `await db.collection("orders").updateOne(..)` to determine whether the document is found and updated as according to the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-updateOne)

Comment: This would not work as I have multiple objects inside ordered_products.